# How to create zero one data for range value matlab

Tags: matlab

Let say I have data a= 1x112; my range value is b = [5 30; 35 54; 56 70;78 99]. How can I create zero one value for that range.

I want, the result is a range from 1:4 = 0, 5:30 = 1, 31:34 = 0, 35:54 = 1, 55 = 0, 56:70 = 1, 
71:77 = 0, 78:99 = 1.

Anyone please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `bsxfun`, element-wise `and` followed by `any`:

```
any(bsxfun(@le,a,b(:,2)) & bsxfun(@ge,a,b(:,1)),1)
```

Might use a lot of memory if you have big data.

Comment: ok get it. but the result is only read start to end value. means that if i use example above, I get the result 5:99=1 other is 0

Comment: Show and example `a` to go with your `b` and run the command. It works how you describe.  And `a` is a row vector.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility: exploiting the order that `b` necessarily has,

```
result = mod(sum(bsxfun(@lt, a, [b(:,1); b(:,2)+1])), 2);
```